# How to write Hasmap<String,Bitmap> to a file Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, hashmap

Trying to write  Hasmap String , Bitmap  to a file and then getting it back to a Hasmap in future;

```
Error : java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap
```

Bitmap is not a Serializable class so how can i wite it to a file and get it back?

```
        //output file 
      fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +"blts/"+"list.ser");
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      oos.writeObject(hashmap);
      oos.close();

        //gethashmap
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +"blts/"+ "list.ser");
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
      HashList = (HashMap<String, Bitmap>)ois.readObject();
      ois.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Serialization

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
currentImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
BitmapDataObject bitmapDataObject = new BitmapDataObject();
bitmapDataObject.serializedBitmap = stream.toByteArray();
bitmapDataObject.serializedBitmap  = "";//your string value
out.writeObject(bitmapDataObject);
```

For De-Serializaton

```
BitmapDataObject bitmapDataObject = (BitmapDataObject) in.readObject();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            bitmapDataObject.imageByteArray, 0,
            bitmapDataObject.imageByteArray.length);
Sting value = bitmapDataObject.getValue();
```

Now you should make your custom class instead of using HashMap

```
public class BitmapDataObject implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String value;
byte[] serializedBitmap;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public byte[] getSerializedBitmap() {
    return serializedBitmap;
}

public void setSerializedBitmap(byte[] serializedBitmap) {
    this.serializedBitmap = serializedBitmap;
}

}
```

Comment: how could i do  this for a hashmap  with  string and bitmap?

Comment: Understand. I think you can do in other way like,

Answer (score 0):

Since HashMap is already Serializable, there is no need to replace it. It is much more convenient to just do a private class that implements the Serializable bitmap.

```
private static class SerializableBitmap implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private byte[] _compressedBitmap;

    // constructor compresses bitmap into Serializable form
    public SerializableBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        _compressedBitmap = stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // reconstructs Bitmap for actual use
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(_compressedBitmap, 0,
                _compressedBitmap.length);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Then you can just use `HashMap<String,SerializableBitmap>` instead of `HashMap<String,Bitmap>`.